# Swift 3: UITabBarController error: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'

Tags: swift, swift3, uikit, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have created a custom tab bar controller. I have done this via Storyboard and it works fine. I am now trying to achieve this through code, without storyboards but I keep getting a crash with this error.

```
'*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'
```

Does anyone know what the issue is? Thank you guys...

```
import UIKit


class SecondController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}

class ThirdController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}

class AnimatedTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    var secondItemImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let secondItemView = self.tabBar.subviews[1]
        self.secondItemImageView = secondItemView.subviews.first as! UIImageView
        self.secondItemImageView.contentMode = .center

    }

    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

        if item.tag == 1 {
            //do our animations
            self.secondItemImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in

                let rotation = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2))
                self.secondItemImageView.transform = rotation

            }, completion: nil)

        }

    }

}

class CustomTabBarController: AnimatedTabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let firstController = ThirdController()
        let firstNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstController)
        firstNavController.title = "Requests"
        firstNavController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "home_selected")
        firstNavController.tabBarItem.tag = 0

        let secondController = SecondController()
        let secondNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondController)
        secondNavController.title = "Messenger"
        secondNavController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "home_selected")
        secondController.tabBarItem.tag = 1

        viewControllers = [firstNavController, secondNavController]

        tabBar.isTranslucent = false

        let topBorder = CALayer()
        topBorder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 0.5)
        topBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

        tabBar.layer.addSublayer(topBorder)
        tabBar.clipsToBounds = true

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I notice:

```
let secondItemView = self.tabBar.subviews[1]
```

In the first line of `AnimatedTabBarController.viewDidLoad()`. However, the tab bar controllers aren't set up until **right** after that in `CustomTabBarController.viewDidLoad()`. I think you'll want to initialize the contained view controllers in your `init` method instead.

Comment: Your comment threw me a little. I'm quite the newbie to swift. Could you please provide an example? I'd really appreciate it. Thank you, Sir.

Comment: It was that line exactly. I just combined both uitabbar controllers into one and make sure the line you mentioned above was run after I added the actual tabbar items and controllers. Cheers!